# What is the name of the application to find automatically the package to install?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management

I would like to know what is the name of the Ubuntu package that finds out for us on the terminal what package to install.

As an example, imagine that I don't have gparted installed. I just open the terminal and type `gparted` on it, and a message like this appears:

```
"gparted" was not found.
The program 'gparted' is currently not installed.  You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

So my question is: What is the name of the package that allows this message to appear ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this reference](http://www.debianadmin.com/manpages/autoaptmanpage.htm), it is [`auto-apt`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/quantal/auto-apt). It will, upon a failure to find an executable file, check the database of files installable by `apt-get` and give the correct package(s) to use. `command-not-found` also appears to perform this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it should be provided by `command-not-found` package. This package also provides the feature that suggests similar command names when your command is not found:

```
$ gdit
No command 'gdit' found, did you mean:
  Command 'edit' from package 'mime-support' (main)
  Command 'gedit' from package 'gedit' (main)
  Command 'gdis' from package 'gdis' (universe)
  Command 'git' from package 'git' (main)
```

Source: [CrunchBang Linux Forums](http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?pid=68258)